# Why does changing my VM's tmp folder permissions cause my rails server to break?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, virtualbox

I'm working on an upload method to s3 and was starting work on it locally. Making sure I understood how to root uploaded files to the proper location. I had it working in the public folder, but as my work is sensitive this clearly was a temporary notion. I switched the filepath over to my 'tmp' folder and my uploader worked! However, when I went to restart my rails server (after adjusting routes), it was not able to  turn off my server properly.

If anyone has run into this before any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: *it was not able to turn off my server properly.* What does that mean? What error were you receiving?

Comment: I was not able to properly sever the connection of my rails server in order to restart it. The error led me to my server.pid, where the console log said a 'server was still running'. Upon rm'ing the file, it caused a rails server error, in which I was unable to close to start up my server again at all.

Comment: To clarify in the error @JustinWood - it was saying: 'a server is already running.' But, I figured out what was going on! I had to halt my vagrant box in order to completely sever the server connection. After doing that, the server.pid was cleared out (not deleted), and everything was fine.